# How can I use a PHP Session variable in a dynamically loaded navbar?

Tags: php

I have a series of pages that load a navbar from an external HTML file like so:

```
<head>
<script>
  $(function() {
  $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar"></div>
<!--other stuff here-->
```

This is all in a PHP page. However, there's part of that navbar that I want to set to set to a PHP $_SESSION variable (a username). Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider change `navbar.html` to `navbar.php`, then replace the username part by:

```
<?php echo($_SESSION["username"] ?>
```

then

```
$("#navbar").load("navbar.php");
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware it would execute the php if I loaded it within the page.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it in the HTML you are including of course, but you could echo it out in your PHP page in a known element:

`<span class='echoedUsername'><?php echo($_SESSION["username"] ?></span>`

and then apply it to an element in your navbar:

`$("#navbar .username").text($('.echoedUsername').text())`